# 3D Scatter Plot in Plotly using DataFrame

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to generate a 3D Scatter chart using plotly.  I've tried two different methods for creating the chart.  Netither one has been successful.  The first code does not do anything.  This was the method that plotly usings in their reference. There is not a traceback error.  No chart is shown or generated.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot,iplot
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
init_notebook_mode()
cf.go_offline()

df.iplot(kind='scatter', mode='markers', x='x', y='y', z='label')
```

This next code provides a "NameError: name 'z' is not defined".  Are there any tricks or tips to creating a 3D scatter from a dataframe?

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot,iplot
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
init_notebook_mode()
cf.go_offline()

trace1 = go.Scatter3d(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y'],
    z=df['label'],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=12,
        color=z,                # set color to an array/list of desired values
        colorscale='Viridis',   # choose a colorscale
        opacity=0.8
    )
)



data = [trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    margin=dict(
        l=0,
        r=0,
        b=0,
        t=0
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='DF')
```

Trace Back:

File "", line 8, in 
    color=z,                # set color to an array/list of desired values

NameError: name 'z' is not defined

The dataframe was generated using the following code:

```
dist = 1 - cosine_similarity(vcx)
MDS()
mds = MDS(n_components=k, dissimilarity="precomputed", random_state=1)
pos = mds.fit_transform(dist)  # shape (n_components, n_samples)
xs, ys = pos[:, 0], pos[:, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=xs, y=ys, label=clusters, title=titles))
```

I have been able to generate a 3D scatter using the dataframe in pyplot but not in plotly.

Comment: How do you generate your dataframe?

Comment: The dataframe was created with using a MDS transformation.  I will add the dataframe code to my question.  I was able to create a 3D scatter in pyplot using the dataframe but not in plotly.

Comment: Did you define your variable `z` before? It does not seem to be a Plotly but simply an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question, but for anyone who want the answer :
Instead of (line 17):

```
        color=z,                         # set color to an array/list of desired values
```

You should put :

```
        color=df['label'],                # set color to an array/list of desired values
```